# Syncing local AD passwords to Microsoft 365

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365

We have a local AD that is many years old. A few months ago, we migrated all our mailboxes from an off-site local Exchange to Microsoft 365. Now we are faced with two passwords per user that have to be managed separately: one for AD authentication and the other for Microsoft 365. We want those passwords to be synced.

1. Is AD Sync the right way to do this?
2. If so, do we need a local Exchange server installed?
3. Will using AD Sync change our local AD in any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Only if you want to manage Exchange related attributes using native tools. Otherwise, you can use ADSIEdit or the attributes tab to manage these attributes.
3. Only if you enable group, device, or password writeback (if you have the appropriate licensing).